# Fix sizes for Imageview in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, view, android-imageview

I have a `LinearLayout` with a list of six horizontal buttons in a column.

Each one has this structure:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_charge" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/view_top_up_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/menu_pay_charge"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_right_small_black" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that each list element has its own size and I can't get a perfect column

How can I set a fixed size for each `ImageView` (without increasing the drawable size)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the `ImageView` a fixed width, e.g. :

```
  <ImageView
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_charge" />
```

Or, you can use `layout_weight`, e.g. :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_charge" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/view_top_up_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/menu_pay_charge"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_right_small_black" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

open the imagens and change to the same size, then add them to the drawable again

try that

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).